# Does default argument of template class, instantiate the template?

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments, template-instantiation

Does the following default argument for the template instantiates a template with type `EmptyClass`?

```
class EmptyClass{};

template <typename TYPE=EmptyClass>
class Sample
{
public:
    static void test()
    {
        TYPE::Serialize();
    }
};
```

Comment: only if you declare an instantiation.

Comment: This didn't give me any compilation error. That means, it doesn't actually instantiates the templates. But I couldn't find any line in C++11 standards that talks about instantiation.

Comment: With templates, nothing is instantiated until you actually *use* the template. Having `static` member function is different, since they don't work on instances.

Comment: What is my doubt is. Does this aforementioned code, instantiates a template with type `EmptyClass`?

Comment: actyaully I am not sure, but afaik adding e.g. a line `typedef Sample<> DoesNotWork;` should create a compiler error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Can you help me with a small snippet?

Comment: Do you declare an instance of `Sample<>` anywhere? If not then no there is no instantiation.

Comment: Oh thanks. You're right. @JoachimPileborg. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, in that code any instance of EmptyClass is created. Serialize is a static function. And EmptyClass's constructor is never called (in code showed)

Comment: The question was not about constructors and objects. It is about template instantiation

Comment: Instance of a template is not an instance of a class which is an instance of a class template. So I do not underszand what your answer has to do with the question. And I can't underszand why this "answer" was excepted...

Answer (score 0):

No. Template are instantiated when used, and are instantiated on a per-function base.

Default parameter values are just the types to use when the parameter is not specified. But does not themselves imply usage.

When you call `Sample<>::test()` then `Sample<Emptyclass>::test()` is instantiated and the `EmptyClass::serialize()` call attempted, resulting in a compile-time error (Since `Emptyclass` is declared as not having such function)

Try to make up more function, containing different compile-time errors referring to different parameter, and you'll see how, until the function is not used, no error is produced.